# My wordpress site is brocken. dont know what todo. Tried safe mode plugin but nothing happen

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site was working fine , but **wordpress update it to V 5.4** and after that my website is not working , not even i can access my admin dashboard.

[image]

I tried all these step to solve this

MANUAL INSTLLATION (RECOMMENDED)

- Download the WP Safe Mode plugin and unzip it, you’ll now have a
  wp-safe-mode folder.
- Connect to your server (for example via FTP) and go to your website
  folder.
- Add this line to your wp-config.php file:

  ```
  if( !defined('WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR') ) define( 'WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR',
  dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-content/wp-safe-mode' ); //WP Safe Mode
  ```
- Create the folder named wp-safe-mode inside your wp-contents folder.
- Uploade the file wp-safe-mode/bootstrap/wp-safe-mode-loader.php into
  the newly created wp-safe-mode folder.
- Upload the entire wp-safe-mode folder to your plugins folder in
  wp-content/plugins.

If your site is broken and you cannot install plugins or access the dashboard, you can modify the loader file temporarily to gain access by following these additional steps:

- Open the plugin file wp-safe-mode-loader.php and change this line:

  ```
  public $safe_mode_on = false;
  ```

  to

  ```
  public $safe_mode_on = true;
  ```
- Upload the modified wp-safe-mode-loader.php file to the
  wp-contents/plugins/wp-safe-mode folder.
- Visit your site, deactivate plugins etc.
- Undo the changes you just made to wp-safe-mode-loader.php when you
  want to disable safe mode.

But nothing works for me. Can you please suggest something so i can fix my problem

Comment: can you check your critical files like index.php, wp-config.php is there something wrong code added ?

Comment: Go to wp-config.php and define('WP_DEBUG', true);  
If this line is already There set it to true add this line as well define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); and refresh your website to see errors.

Comment: @UsmanMunir when i change debug false to true it gives me
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
it gives me this

Answer (score 0):

**Theme Conflict Troubleshoot:**

To perform this, you just activate a default theme, like Twenty Nineteen. Unfortunately, because your site is showing an error, you will need to perform the troubleshoot with either your web host’s file manager (like cPanel’s Filemanager), or use FTP or sFTP (it’s like secure version of FTP.) It’s important to note that in switching themes, you won’t lose your chosen theme’s settings. To do this, you rename your active theme’s folder by adding DISABLE or OFF to the end of the folder’s name. For example, if you’re using Twenty Eighteen and the folder is ‘twentyeighteen’, you would name it ‘twentyeighteenDISABLE’ or ‘twentyeighteenOLD’ . Go back to the front of your site and refresh.

The objective is to check whether the mistake leaves. In the event that it doesn’t, it is anything but a subject issue. Try to rename the organizer back to its unique name when you’re finished investigating.

**Plugin Conflict Troubleshoot**

If it’s not the theme, it might be a plugin issue. In a way, troubleshooting is similar. However, it’s much easier to rename the plugin folder to ‘pluginsOFF’. Visit the site, and log-in. This will turn off all of the plugins. Please note that it won’t remove the original settings of those plugins, as they will be there when you reactivate them later on.

Once the plugins are off, go back and rename the folder back to ‘plugins’. Go to your WordPress admin area and reactivate each, one-by-one, until you get the screen that says “There has been a critical error on your website”. The plugin that you just reactivated, is the problem.

You can either disable the plugin that caused the problem or remove it or roll it back to the previous version using the rollback plugin and wait until the developer releases a new version of the plugin.